# How Does Wooly Bully 2's Waterproof Wings Variant Work?

Tags: wooly-bully

I've started an online game of Wooly Bully (La Guerre des Moutons) 2 with the waterproof wings variant "on", but I'm not 100% sure how this rule plays out in practice.

The key line in the rulebook seems to be:

> 2 enclosed fields containing the same color of sheep separated by the
>   same pond are considered a single enclosure.

But can you have a "superfield" of more than 2 enclosed fields joined together by ponds?  What if a Wolf cancels out a field adjoining its Forest - does this cancel out fields of the same colour on the other side of ponds too?  (Does the Wolf get water wings of his own, in other words?)